# How to close connection of org.apache.http.client.HttpClient object

Tags: java, sockets, httpclient

I am not getting any method to close 'client' object. i am doing as part of fortify bug to close socket.

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

Here, I have to close this but not able to find any close method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use HttpClients.createDefault(); method which returns a CloseableHttpClient object that can be closed manually.
more info here :
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_httpclient/apache_httpclient_closing_connection.htm